# How do you use pyautogui/win32gui and Pillow together?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pywin32

I'm working on my first big project on Python - Inspired by the Chris Kiehl sushi go round tutorial, I'm building a bot that plays a text sim game using gui automation and basic computer vision. I want to use Pillow to take screenshots and gui apis to manipulate the operating system but I can make scripts that do either but not both. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong - any help would be really appreciated - thanks.

Here's an abridged version of what I'm trying to do:

```
def match_loop():
    global home_or_away
    box = (x_pad+1,y_pad+1,x_pad+806,y_pad+629)
    im2 = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    time.sleep(1)
    mousePos((x_pad+49, y_pad+149))
    leftClick()
    time.sleep(1)
    if home_or_away == "home":
        mousePos((x_pad+175, y_pad+543))
        leftClick()
        mousePos((x_pad+49, y_pad+149))
    else:
        mousePos((x_pad+728, y_pad+543))
        leftClick()
        mousePos((x_pad+49, y_pad+149))
    im2.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap_' + str(int(time.time()))+'.png', 'PNG')
    while im2.getpixel((33,136)) != (206,203,214) : #while it's the first half
        im2 = ImageGrab.grab(box)
        im2.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap_' + str(int(time.time()))+'.png', 'PNG')
        time.sleep(1)        
        if im2.getpixel((33,136)) == (206,203,214): #if's the secondhalf
            secondhalf()
    secondhalf()
```

The code above runs fine but the code below runs into a syntax error after the mousePos function call, which works in the function above, no matter what I put afterwards:

```
def subsaudit():
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap_' + '.png', 'PNG')
    if im.getpixel((124,399)) or im.getpixel((125,399)) or im.getpixel((126,399)) or im.getpixel((127,399)) or im.getpixel((128,399)) or im.getpixel((129,399)) or im.getpixel((130,399)) or im.getpixel((131,399)) or im.getpixel((132,399)) or im.getpixel((133,399)) or im.getpixel((134,399)) or im.getpixel((135,399)) or im.getpixel((136,399)) or im.getpixel((137,399)) != (0,0,66):
        subscount = 1
    if im.getpixel((124,419)) or im.getpixel((125,419)) or im.getpixel((126,419)) or im.getpixel((127,419)) or im.getpixel((128,419)) or im.getpixel((129,419)) or im.getpixel((130,419)) or im.getpixel((131,419)) or im.getpixel((132,419)) or im.getpixel((133,419)) or im.getpixel((134,419)) or im.getpixel((135,419)) or im.getpixel((136,419)) or im.getpixel((137,419)) != (0,0,66):
        subscount = 2  
    if subscount >= 1 :
        mousePos(((x_pad+178, y_pad+399))
        time.sleep(1)
        leftClick()
        box = (x_pad+1,y_pad+1,x_pad+806,y_pad+629)
        im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
        im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap_' + '.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: Ok, I'll bite. Why have you got two functions with the same name `screenGrab()` ? And what are you actually trying to do? And what doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to make a bot that plays Championship Manager 01/02. Since the OP, I've mostly got the basic loop down, but I'm trying to build the function that gets the player ratings and makes gameplay decisions upon them. The first function takes screenshots until a pixel changes to signify the end of the first half. The second function is to assess the number of players on the bench and their stats to decide who to sub on if someone's injured - it keeps getting a syntax error at the 10th line, even if I delete or replace the exisiting time.sleep call.

Comment: You can't test lots of conditions in your `if` statement like that, you need `if (a==6) or (b==6) or (c==6):`

Comment: Thanks - I've fixed that part now and defined the box value at that top of the function but I still run into the syntax error. I've imported the time module at the top of the script.